# What is the purpose of 'to be' in this sentence and is it grammatically incorrect if it is omitted?

Tags: to-be-deletion

> It (Parasite) is the first-ever South Korean film **to be** nominated for an Oscar.

A student of mine asked me why there is 'to be' in this sentence.

What is the purpose of 'to be' in this sentence and is it grammatically incorrect if it is omitted?

So:

> It is the first-ever South Korean film nominated for an Oscar.

Comment: The verb is necessary because the tense may change : the first _to have been_ // the first _that will be_ // the first _that was_ //

Answer (score 1):

There is a familiar pattern: **the first [noun] to [verb phrase]**.  The verb phrase could be **run in the Boston Marathon** or it could be **be nominated for an Oscar**.  You can indeed omit **to be** without changing the meaning, but then the phrase no longer fits the pattern, and for that reason I think the sentence takes on a more literary register.

Comment: I agree with that but I also think that the "to be" form emphasises the significance, particularly the historical significance, of the achievement. For example "Barack Obama was the first person of colour to be elected President of the US"  as against "Donald Trump is the first person with orange skin elected President of the US". The first achievement is culturally and politically significant, the second is merely a curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adjectival verb phrase formed in the passive voice.  In this case, the verb in the adjectival phrase (to be) is not declined, but is kept to indictate that the subject is the target of the action.

Answer (score 0):

> It (Parasite) is the first-ever South Korean film to be nominated for
>   an Oscar.

"To be nominated for an Oscar" is an infinitival relative clause. This use (labeled as non-modal in CGEL) is rather special in that it usually requires words like : first, second, next, last .. It receives past interpretation - ..that was nominated/ to have been nominated.